# jQuery DOM Insertion with variable insert-method

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code uses a jQuery plugin that inserts some HTML code.

I have the option to change the inserting method, by setting them via variable.

The variable is called:

```
var options = {insert: 'append'};
```

I don't want to do that with an `if` condition, like that:

```
if(options.insert === 'append') {
 $('#foobar').append(htmlcode);
}else if (options.insert === 'prepend'){
 $('#foobar').prepend(htmlcode);
```

... and so on.

Is there any solution to insert the html code with a given varibale method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the jQuery construct is an object, you can use bracket notation to access functions. Try this:

```
$('#foobar')[options.insert](htmlcode);
```

So long as `options.insert` matches the name of a function, it'll work.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/VbA6K/)

Comment: Nice one. I didn't know about that.

Comment: Good answer. Newer thought about this :)